# Paste data Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I am pasting a lot of data during a VBA macro in excel and for some reason when it pastes, it puts the data at a random point in the sheet and I am not sure why.  I have pasted the paste command below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sheet5.Range("A1", "AH5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheet9.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want this pasted? I am going to assume you want it pasted in cell A1 on Sheet9. Change "Sheet9.Range("A1") to whatever you need (ie Sheet9.Range("B1") to paste into cell B1).

```
Sheet5.Range("A1", "AH5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet9.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it pasts the  data into active(marked) cell on the Sheet9, am I right? You should specify a cell in the second line of your code.